# SQL : how to translate rows to one field?

Tags: sql, sql-server

as title,

SQL:

> select * from table

data:

```
id     b    c   d   

4      17   Q   1   
5      17   Z   9   
6      17   G   5   
7      18   Q   3
```

I need following result:

```
b    field

17   Q:1,Z:9,G:5
18   Q:3
```

how can I change the SQL statement?
thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
SELECT  b, STUFF((select ', ' + c + ': ' + cast(d as varchar)
        FROM table xt
        WHERE xt.b = t.b
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '')
FROM table t
GROUP BY b
```